# How does a website know if i've visited it before? (and how to bypass that)

Tags: cookies, tor, websites

For example: https://pdfcandy.com/pdf-ocr.html has a limit on how many times I can use a feature per hour, but if I use an incognito tab I can easily bypass that.

But with https://ichigoreader.com/upload (don't judge I'm trying to translate a horror manga I like) Even going as far as creating a new identity on Tor, it KNOWS it's me and doesn't let me go beyond the limit.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Questions on how to bypass security measures or other limits for your own gain are off-topic here. If you want to know what techniques there are in general for tracking/identifying users - there are already questions about this here.

Comment: I don't know how often TOR switches exit nodes and if it can be done manually. If you're on the same one, you're using the same IP address.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fight browser fingerprinting?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23053/how-to-fight-browser-fingerprinting)

Comment: If I were the site maintainer, I wouldn't even try to recognize you. There would be no need. *I would classify and recognize the manga*.

Comment: You tagged this with the easiest answer: cookies.

Comment: There are numerous ways a site could do this. We can't list them all. And we are not going to inspect that site to get specific.